# Send pdf as byte Array to front end and download a file JAVA (Play framework)

Tags: java, pdf, playframework, binary, arrays

I'm creating pdf on my backend java application. when I save bytearray (my pdf file) on server storage pdf file is ok... I can open it looks good (98kb)

When I send this byte array as response for my request to a browser and save file as pdf on client computer only what I see after openning pdf is blank page. Weight of pdf(client) is bigger 128kB which is wierd.

I assume the problem is somewhere inside my javascript code:

```
$http
    .post("/myUrl", JSON.stringify({img1: chart1URL,img2: chart2URL, img3: chart3URL,img4: chart4URL,img5: chart5URL,img6: chart6URL, site: $scope.criteria.siteNames[0], ward: $scope.criteria.wardNames[0]}),

        {})
    .success(
        function(data){
            debugger;
            //var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/*'});
            //var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //window.open(objectUrl);
            var blob=new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download="testFile.pdf";
            link.click();
        }
    );
};
```

Why test file is bigger then file on backend?

I attach also backend code:

```
File file = ("myCorrectFile.pdf");
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
response().setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=test.pdf");
            return ok(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the ajax call to be post? This can also be accomplished by get method as well. 
The whole javascript code can be replaced by something like

```
window.open("url?param=" + parameters, "_self")
```

but get method has its own disadvantage of having maximum URL length of 2048 characters, depends how big your url would be.